# gnuplot x-axis extending past contour border

Tags: gnuplot, border, axis, contour

I am plotting a simple contour in gnuplot. The x-axis is being stubborn and keeps extending past the set range, leaving a weird gap between the end of the contour and the border. The data set extends past the max in the range. 
Here is my code:

```
set term epslatex  size 8.5in, 5.1in
set output "static10OF2contour.tex"

data = "static10OF2contour.data"

set xtics 2.5
set xrange[-10:10]   
set cbrange [0.9:2.6]

set pm3d map explicit interpolate 0,0
set palette defined (0 0 0 0.5, 1 0 0 1, 2 0 0.5 1, 3 0 1 1, 4 0.5 1 0.5, 5 1 1 0, 6 1 0.5 0, 7 1 0 0, 8 0.5 0 0)

splot data using 1:2:3 with pm3d notitle
```

Here is the image is produces with the gap seen on the right hand side of the image.

[image]

Finally, sample of the data file in x,y,z

```
  -10.2441626       0.00000000       1.04107463    
  -10.2441626       22.5000000       1.04107463    
  -10.2441626       45.0000000       1.04277849    
  -10.2441626       67.5000000       1.04277849    
  -10.2441626       90.0000000       1.04107463    
  -10.2441626       112.500000       1.04107463    
  -10.2441626       135.000000       1.04107463    
  -10.2441626       157.500000       1.04107463    
  -10.2441626       180.000000       1.04107463    

  -9.99016190       0.00000000       1.03766692    
  -9.99016190       22.5000000       1.03937078    
  -9.99016190       45.0000000       1.03937078    
  -9.99016190       67.5000000       1.03937078    
  -9.99016190       90.0000000       1.03937078    
  -9.99016190       112.500000       1.03937078    
  -9.99016190       135.000000       1.03766692    
  -9.99016190       157.500000       1.03766692    
  -9.99016190       180.000000       1.03937078    

  -9.73616219       0.00000000       1.03766692    
  -9.73616219       22.5000000       1.03766692    
  -9.73616219       45.0000000       1.03766692    
  -9.73616219       67.5000000       1.03766692    
  -9.73616219       90.0000000       1.03766692    
  -9.73616219       112.500000       1.03766692    
  -9.73616219       135.000000       1.03766692    
  -9.73616219       157.500000       1.03766692    
  -9.73616219       180.000000       1.03937078
```

This goes on until x=11.09, so it should theoretically have no problem stopping at x=10. I have tried setting the max x-range to 11.09 or even 12, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm... strange. Which version of gnupot are your running? Could you maybe somehow provide or link to the full data for reproducing and testing?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving in the xrange one of the values you have in your x array. So, given the data set you provided, if you type

```
xmin=-10.2441626
xmax=-9.73616219
set xrange[xmin:xmax]
```

it should produce a plot with no blank line.